# Basic question about firebase real time database. Is there a good pattern for hiding the implementations from the UI?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Many of the online tutorials I see for firebase show hard coded implementations in the GUI classes, for flutter, widget classes, for Android, the activity class.

Is it redundant to provide another layer of abstraction for the realtime database?

I know firebase is accessed as a singleton.  Can I extend it in some way? I want to hide the code and firebase class `set()` and `update()` methods, etc

I just want to be able to swap my database out for another one later on down the line if need be.

Could I extend the firebase class, or get the instance in a separate `DatabaseFacade` and pass it an interface reference for GUI or widget callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

I usually access the database directly in my widgets simply because it's so convenient.

But I also have a bigger app where I wrapped everything in DAO/DTO classes, and that works fine too. There is no way to extend the Firebase classes that I know off though, so I started with a central `Manager` class that then provides access to al the data access methods and classes.